# RAD Studio translation editor - filter user viewable items

Tags: delphi, translation

In translation editor, in RAD Studio XE7, is there a possibility, to filter only items (strings), that are actually visible to the user in runtime?

Here is how it looks like:

[image: Translation editor]

I can use "Show only strings" option in "Filters", which is nice, as it removes a huge lot of stuff, that cannot be translated at all, but there still is a majority of strings, that also don't need to be translated. The user will never see `Caption.Font.Name` of a `TPanel`, a version nor a whole bunch of other component properties. So in other words - can I filter only captions, hints and other "visible" stuff?

I am adding a "Delphi" tag, since it is the language I use, but it is really not language-specific or related question.

Comment: No, there is no filter for "only visible stuff". A font may need to change with the language, as well as a version number. But in addition to using filter `Show only strings` you can remove `Show Don't Translate`, and then once go true the list and set status `Don't Translate` for those that clutters the list. If you have focus on the `Status` field, simply press `D` to set the status. Goes quite fast with arrow down - D - arrow down - D etc.

Comment: That is a good idea with the D key, it will speed up things a lot. Thank you